# enumerations in C from a c++ perspective

Tags: c++, c, enums

I am a C++ programmer and I rarely have to deal with GCC "C". I am currently converting some code from C++ to C for use with the GCC compiler.

In C++ I would use the following source code. Note that I would use a class for scope.

**C++ Source**

```
class Card {
public:
   enum Suit {
      Diamonds, Hearts, Clubs, Spades
   };
};

class Weapon {
public:
   enum WeaponType {
      Rocks, Clubs, Guns
   };
};

int main () {
 Suit a = Card::Clubs; 
 WeaponType b = Weapon::Clubs
}
```

In "C" with no classes and no way of differentiation between the two different "clubs" keywords. I get the following error message when trying to compile this

> error C2365: 'Clubs' : redefinition; previous definition was
>   'enumerator'

**C Source**

```
enum Suit {
    Diamonds, Hearts, Clubs, Spades
};

enum WeaponType {
    Rocks, Clubs, Guns
};

int main () {
 Suit a = Clubs; 
 WeaponType b = Clubs
}
```

So my questions are

- How do I declare two different enum in the same file with the same keyword?
- How do I add scope to the enum so I can assign different variables different enum with the same enum name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do it just like the old days:

```
enum Suit {
    ST_Diamonds, ST_Hearts, ST_Clubs, ST_Spades
};

enum WeaponType {
    WT_Rocks, WT_Clubs, WT_Guns
};

int main () {
 Suit a = ST_Clubs; 
 WeaponType b = WT_Clubs;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I always prefered the type on the end: Club_Suit, Club_Weapon, because it was closer to english language syntax.  I head toward the Club_Building, with my Club_Weapon.  Same difference in the end though.

Comment: @Mooing Duck By the end of the day, it's just a naming convention preference. As long as it makes sense and is consistent, it should be fine :) I persoanally prefer the type to be a prefix because in English we read from left to right, so I see right off the bat what type it belongs to.

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done in standard C.  From *C A Reference Manual*: "Identifiers declared as enumeration constants are in the same overloading class as variables functions and typedef names", so enumeration constants must be unique in a given scope.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the lack of namespaces in C your only option is prefixing:

```
enum Weapon {
    WeaponRocks,
    WeaponSocks,
    ...
};
```